# Uing Openpyxl to get a column of data and generate a list for math manipulations

Tags: python, excel

I am a python newbie
I am trying to use openpyxl module in python 2.7 to get a column of numbers, putting them in a list and add them togother.

I am having trouble using the for loop because it gives out the updated list in each cycle. How can I get the "final" list only using other methods?

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl

ac = openpyxl.load_workbook('Financial Sample.xlsx')

sheet = ac.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

l=[]

sum = 0

for i in range(2,10):

    sub = int(sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value)

    l.append(sub)

    print(l)

    #for x in []:

        #sum = sum + x

        #print(sum)
```

Thank you!

Comment: just drop the indentation on `print(l)`, you'll get only one print: the final one.

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you starting with Python 2? The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.